# Angular 6 PWA with Node not working

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular-service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a Angular 6 app that works and registers the SW when served with 
`http-server --port 8080` command as you can see here:
[image]

[image]

But when I serve the files from my Node / Express application that they are meant to be served. The service worker won't register, tried running the app from localhost and also from Heroku but it's the same. Application works otherwise. Any idea what can cause this?

[image]

Comment: Any error in the console, or in the security tab in the debug tools?

Comment: @David Console is clean, Security tab says just "This page is not secure."

Comment: You need to have a valid https website for the service worker to register if you are  not using localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this issue is to do with the path that `@angular/cli` uses when registering the service worker, I have found registering the service worker in `main.ts` to be more reliable:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(() => {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && environment.production) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('ngsw-worker.js');
  }
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Or, looking at [this recent comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8515#issuecomment-394065254) you can manually modify the path in `app.modules.ts`

```
-ServiceWorkerModule.register('./ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
+ServiceWorkerModule.register('.ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
```

Comment: I have base href "/" so I think that should not be an issue. I tried the second tip anyway with no success. Maybe I try that main.ts workaround.

Comment: I use the main.ts one in my own projects, have never actually tried the second one myself. Will avoid it now though, thanks!

Comment: main.ts thing works but I had to make sure I was in production mode via `ng build --prod` which for some reason I had missed of in `package.json`. Linked my question to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55362319/how-do-i-deploy-angular-app-to-heroku-and-keep-as-pwa

Answer (score 0):

I also had a same issue that worked locally but not herokou, and as a result of various searches on the net, I came to this page.

In my case, I finally solved it by adding `--prod` to the ng build. With `--prod`, the settings in environment.prod.ts will be reflected, the "serivice worker" in production in angular.json will be true, also `"enabled" -> true` in `ServiceWorkerModule.register` in `app.module.ts`, and service worker is now working. FYI.