# How do I deploy Angular App to Heroku and keep as PWA?

Tags: angular, heroku, progressive-web-apps

**Summarize the problem**:

I'm trying to deploy my Angular 6 App to Heroku and keep the progressive web app features. There's no service worker for the end build on Heroku.

**Background**:

I've built a local Sports Store app in Angular 6. I'm following the book *Pro Angular 6, 3rd Edition. by Adam Freeman* and have gotten the app to roughly the stage at the end of chapter 9.

GitHub repository of chapter 9: [SportsStore](https://github.com/Apress/pro-angular-6/tree/master/09%20-%20SportsStore%20-%20Admin/SportsStore)

To create this as a PWA I've run

`ng add @angular/pwa`

I edited the generated `ngsw-config.json` so it matches [this](https://github.com/Apress/pro-angular-6/blob/master/10%20-%20SportsStore%20-%20PWA%20and%20Deployment/SportsStore/ngsw-config.json) shown below in *Code*

Following the blog post [here](https://medium.com/@hellotunmbi/how-to-deploy-angular-application-to-heroku-1d56e09c5147)
I've done the following steps:

1. `npm install --save express path`
2. edited `package.json` moving `@angular/cli`, `@angular/compiler-cli`, `typescript` and `@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8"` from devDependencies over to dependencies
3. Created `server.js`
4. Created `Procfile` with `web: node server.js`

```
heroku create sportsstoredemo
git add .
git commit -m "setup'
git push heroku master
```

This deploys on heroku but does not include the service worker. I'm lost what I can do as I barely understand the steps I've taken above.

Can someone take the GitHub repo and advise what steps will get this on Heroku with service worker running or point out where I have gone wrong?

**Code**

`ngsw-config.json`

```js
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [{
    "name": "app",
    "installMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/favicon.ico",
        "/index.html",
        "/*.css",
        "/*.js"
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**",
        "/font/*"
      ]
    }
  }],
  "dataGroups": [
    {
        "name": "api-product",
        "urls": ["/api/products"],
        "cacheConfig" : {
            "maxSize": 100,
            "maxAge": "5d"
        }
    }],
    "navigationUrls": [
      "/**"
    ]
}
```

`package.json`

```js
{
  "name": "sports-store",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "json": "json-server data.js -p 3500 -m authMiddleware.js",
    "postinstall": "ng build --prod"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.15.3",
    "npm": "6.4.1"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2",
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.12.4",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~7.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "json-server": "^0.14.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0"
  }
}
```

`server.js`

```js
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Serve static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/MY_APP_NAME'));

// Send all requests to index.html
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/MY_APP_NAME/index.html'));
});

// default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

**Describe expected and actual results**

Expected - same app as code [SportsStore](https://github.com/Apress/pro-angular-6/tree/master/09%20-%20SportsStore%20-%20Admin/SportsStore) but running as PWA on Heroku

Actual - just Angular App only when built on Heroku. Locally I can get this running as PWA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found at
[Angular 6 PWA with Node not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089478/angular-6-pwa-with-node-not-working)

Can someone mark my question as duplicate?

In `main.ts` the following works:-

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(() => {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && environment.production) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('ngsw-worker.js');
  }
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I had to also edit my `package.json` from  `"build": "ng build"` to `"build": "ng build --prod"`

Below was going to be my update post until I found the above, I'll leave it here incase it's useful to anyone.

> ## Rubber Ducking
>
> I've had not found an answer to this so I've posted my progress so far in an  attempt to Rubber Duck my problem in such a way anyone can follow.
>
> #### Step 1: Get Angular 6 App running locally as PWA
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/Apress/pro-angular-6
> cd pro-angular-6
> cd "09 - SportsStore - Admin"
> cd SportsStore
> ng add @angular/pwa
> ```
>
> So per the [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started) >this last command is adding the `@angular/service-worker` package by adding the  `ServiceWorkerModule` and registering `ngsw-worker.js` to `app.component.ts` Ok
>
> Running the following builds the project and creates the `/dist` folder containing  `ngsw-worker.js`
>
> ```
> ng build --prod
> ```
>
> Running the following means I can locally get this running as a PWA.
>
> ```
> http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/SportsStore
> ```
>
> Not too relevant but opening separate cmd and running the following populates the app with data.
>
> ```
> npm run json
> ```
>
> #### Step 2: Get Angular 6 App running on Heroku
>
> So edited `package.json` moving `@angular/cli`, `@angular/compiler-cli`, `typescript` and `@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8"` from devDependencies over > to dependencies
>
> [This](https://medium.com/@hellotunmbi/how-to-deploy-angular-application-to-heroku-1d56e09c5147) blog post suggest `"postinstall": "ng build --aot --prod"` rather than `"ng build --prod"`. Let's try that.
>
> Ran
>
> ```
> npm install express path --save
> ```
>
> Added `server.js` with same code as OP. I had some issues with this using a `./dist` > from someone else blog post but changed this back to `/dist`
>
> Edited to `"start": "node server.js"` in package.json. Well that's different at least
>
> Deploy to **heroku** (roughly along lines of)
>
> ```
> heroku login
> git init
> git add -A
> git commit -m "test"
> heroku git:remote -a APP_NAME
> git push heroku master
> ```